# Why does this Regex only match at the start of the line in Python?

Tags: python, regex

In Python I can do

```
import re
re.match("m", "mark")
```

and I get the expected result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='m'>
```

But it only works if the pattern is at the start of the string:

```
re.match("m", "amark")
```

gives `None`.  There is noting about that pattern which requires it to be at the start of the string - no `^` or similar.  Indeed it works as expected on [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/).

Does Python have some special behaviour - and how do I disable it please?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one marked. Yes the answers are duplicates, but the question comes at the problem from a completely different angle.  I would have to have known the answer to my question to recognise the other as a "duplicate".

Comment: It is a dupe by all means, if not that one, there is another one regarding `re.match`. BTW, `re.match` is not matching at the start of a *line*, it only matches at the start of a *string*.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't a dupe.  I said it wasn't a dupe of the one marked.  It should be marked as a dupe of a question it's a dupe of, not of some other one.

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate. Besides, the documentation for `re.match` clearly says that it tries to "apply the pattern at the start of the string." A few moments of research would have been well-spent here.

Comment: I'd like to note that the question phrased in this fashion made it possible for me to find an answer. I did read the docs, but I missed that on my first pass. 
Thank you for asking this question.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth You and (at least) 10 other people, apparently, judging by the  number of up-votes on the answer to date.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the docs on [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning* of `string` match the regular expression `pattern`, return a corresponding match object.

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to search the entire string.

The docs even grant this issue its own chapter, outlining the differences between the two: [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: *Repetitio est mater studiorum*.

Comment: *et suppositio nil ponit in esse.*

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
re.match("[^m]*m", "mark")
```

`match` matches from beginning of string.So you need to give it a way to match the start of string if `m` is not at start of string.